# Desktop Icons are overlapping ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, icons, desktop-icons

I just restarted my system and now desktop icons have two copies and one is overlapping with other. I tried to resposition the icons but I am not able to rearrae the icons also.

[image: This is the screenshot of the desktop]

.When I tried to select the icons I am only able to select the foreground icons. It looks as if two desktop are running together. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have updated the version in the title